# Error on VBA during conversion from PDF to Doc file in MS Access

Tags: vba, pdf, error-handling, ms-word, runtime-error

I am try to convert MS Access Report "Premier Practice" to PDF file "Premier Practice.pdf" than convert to Premier Practice.doc. Finally open Premier Practice.doc
I am getting error: Error 462 in VBA : remote server machine not found

and sometime I get this error: Run time error -'2147023170(8000706be)'Automation Error: The remote procedure call failed -
it highlights ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Owner\Documents"

Below is VBA Code in MS Access:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Premier Practice", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Premier Practice.PDF"
DoEvents
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
  file = Dir("C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Premier Practice.pdf") 'pdf path
  Do While (file <> "")
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\"
          Documents.Open FileName:=file, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:= _
        False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:= _
        "", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\" 'path for saving word
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=Replace(file, ".pdf", ".doc"), FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument _
        , LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
        WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
        SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
        False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.Close
    file = Dir
  Loop

DoEvents
DoCmd.RunMacro "Open Word"
End Sub


DoCmd.RunMacro "Open Word"
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
  Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open _
      ("C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Premier Practice.doc")
  WordApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: Those lines are completely unnecessary. Just delete them. You're already passing the full file name and path in the `file` variable, which is all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me which lines is not necessary.

Comment: `ChangeFileOpenDirectory`